# Rescaling bitmap downloaded in Universal Image Loader before caching rescaled images

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for displaying a bitmap in an ImageView. But when the bitmap is downloaded I want to rescale it and then that rescaled bitmap should be cached.... I am not able to identify that point at which modification is required to fulfill my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIL `DisplayImageOptions` has an `imageScaleType` parameter which takes an `ImageScaleType`.  [The docs for `ImageScaleType`](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/assist/ImageScaleType.java) make clear that that scaling happens before the image is cached:

> ```
> /**
> * Image will scaled-down exactly to target size (scaled width or height or both
> * will be equal to target size; depends on ImageView's scale type). Use it if
> * memory economy is critically important.
> * Note: If original image size is smaller than target size then original image
> * won't be scaled.
> * 
> * NOTE: For creating result Bitmap (of exact size) additional Bitmap will be
> * created with Bitmap#createBitmap(...)
> * Cons: Saves memory by keeping smaller Bitmap in memory cache (comparing with
> * IN_SAMPLE... scale types)
> * Pros: Requires more memory in one time for creation of result Bitmap.
> */
> ```

So, set ImageScaleType in your DisplayOptions and enjoy the scaled bitmaps in your cache.